Nvidia drivers 545 and up prevent steam games from launching and a host of other issues
I've been having issues with all nvidia drivers version 545 and up.

The driver updates and downgrades themselves fail. Ubuntu Drivers will throw an error and the driver will be poorly installed. it seems if you ever go between any of the drivers between 545 and 560 there will be errors. To be able to go anywhere from there it is required to use the drivers app to revert to nouveau, to do a full purge with apt of nvidia* and then autoremove, autoclean and install -f, then reboot and then lastly attempt to install an nvidia driver anew. From such a state installing 535 will succeed without error. (I can't get the other ones to install reliably without error. 560 seems to error out less often, it doesn't error out on a fresh install but 545 errors out always even on a fresh install).
Games on steam don't start under 560. steam shows them "running" but nothing starts.
Second screen will get forgotten, re-detected at the wrong resolution or framerate, cause display manager to crash
systemctl suspend will not wake correctly on 545 and up (blackscreen)

All of these issues and potentially much much more I haven't cataloged.
I'd like to be able to benefit from the new driver's performance uplift but right now am stuck on 535
I'm on a GTX1070
tsu                         
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: All Series (All)
    vendor: ASUS
    version: System Version
    serial: System Serial Number
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=desktop family=ASUS MB frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=All uuid=25a7d940-d7da-11dd-9a37-74d02ba1af42
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Z87-K
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: Rev X.0x
       serial: 130612577301748
       slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1402
          date: 11/05/2014
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 8MiB
          capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 1
          size: 24GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: KHX1600C9D3/8GX
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 0
             serial: 692C358D
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: KHX1600C9D3/4GX
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 1
             serial: 2C3E18EC
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: KHX1600C9D3/8GX
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 2
             serial: 652C588D
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: KHX1600C9D3/4GX
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 3
             serial: 333E01FE
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 4d
          slot: CPU Internal L1
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: internal write-back
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 4e
          slot: CPU Internal L2
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 4f
          slot: CPU Internal L3
          size: 8MiB
          capacity: 8MiB
          capabilities: internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 53
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.60.3
          slot: SOCKET 1150
          size: 4GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts vnmi md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 microcode=40 threads=8
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 06
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f6000000-f70fffff ioport:e0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:33 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: GP104 High Definition Audio Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                logical name: card2
                logical name: /dev/snd/controlC2
                logical name: /dev/snd/hwC2D0
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D3p
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D7p
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D8p
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D9p
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:f7080000-f7083fff
              *-input:0
                   product: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: input10
                   logical name: /dev/input/event10
              *-input:1
                   product: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
                   physical id: 1
                   logical name: input11
                   logical name: /dev/input/event11
              *-input:2
                   product: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
                   physical id: 2
                   logical name: input12
                   logical name: /dev/input/event12
              *-input:3
                   product: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
                   physical id: 3
                   logical name: input9
                   logical name: /dev/input/event9
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:f7200000-f720ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 6.8.0-41-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 6.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=14 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Mouse
                   product: SteelSeries ApS Ikari Laser
                   vendor: SteelSeries ApS
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@3:1
                   logical name: input19
                   logical name: /dev/input/event2
                   logical name: input19::capslock
                   logical name: input19::compose
                   logical name: input19::kana
                   logical name: input19::numlock
                   logical name: input19::scrolllock
                   logical name: input20
                   logical name: /dev/input/event3
                   logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
                   logical name: input21
                   logical name: /dev/input/event4
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00 usb
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=50mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Audio device
                   product: Samson C03U
                   vendor: Samson Technologies
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@3:3
                   logical name: card1
                   logical name: /dev/snd/controlC1
                   logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: usb-1.10 audio-control
                   configuration: driver=snd-usb-audio maxpower=90mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: USB hub
                   product: USB2.0 Hub
                   vendor: Genesys Logic, Inc.
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@3:4
                   version: 32.98
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Keyboard
                      product: Fnatic Gear RUSH Mechanical Keyboard
                      vendor: Fnatic Gear
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: usb@3:4.2
                      logical name: input5
                      logical name: /dev/input/event5
                      logical name: input5::capslock
                      logical name: input5::numlock
                      logical name: input5::scrolllock
                      logical name: input6
                      logical name: /dev/input/event6
                      logical name: input7
                      logical name: /dev/input/event7
                      version: 1.09
                      capabilities: usb-2.00 usb
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Generic USB device
                      product: BCM20702A0
                      vendor: Broadcom Corp
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: usb@3:4.3
                      version: 1.12
                      serial: 5CF3709927BE
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=btusb speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:3
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: Microsoft X-Box One Elite 2 pad
                   vendor: Microsoft
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@3:6
                   logical name: input24
                   logical name: /dev/input/event19
                   logical name: /dev/input/js0
                   version: 4.08
                   serial: 3032363330303432383533393437
                   capabilities: usb-2.00 usb
                   configuration: driver=xpad maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 6.8.0-41-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 6.08
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Mass storage device
                   product: DataTraveler 3.0
                   vendor: Kingston
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@4:2
                   logical name: scsi6
                   version: 1.10
                   serial: E0D55EA493BDE3B1A9620026
                   capabilities: usb-3.20 scsi emulated scsi-host
                   configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=504mA speed=5000Mbit/s
                 *-disk
                      description: SCSI Disk
                      product: DataTraveler 3.0
                      vendor: Kingston
                      physical id: 0.0.0
                      bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
                      logical name: /dev/sdb
                      version: PMAP
                      serial: EE03DB515AE9
                      size: 115GiB (124GB)
                      capabilities: removable
                      configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                    *-medium
                         physical id: 0
                         logical name: /dev/sdb
                         size: 115GiB (124GB)
                         capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                         configuration: guid=edcebe78-f601-4150-a2b4-bad32975584b
                       *-volume
                            description: EXT4 volume
                            vendor: Linux
                            physical id: 1
                            logical name: /dev/sdb1
                            logical name: /media/t/jacques
                            version: 1.0
                            serial: 5fd7625e-9567-4b9b-bc51-8b9d614d6e3d
                            size: 115GiB
                            capacity: 115GiB
                            capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                            configuration: created=2024-08-14 01:06:01 filesystem=ext4 label=jacques lastmountpoint=/media/t/jacques modified=2024-08-27 00:47:58 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2024-08-27 00:47:58 state=mounted
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:31 memory:f721a000-f721a00f
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:20 memory:f7218000-f72183ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 6.8.0-41-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 6.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.04
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             logical name: card0
             logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D1p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D2c
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:32 memory:f7210000-f7213fff
           *-input:0
                product: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic
                physical id: 0
                logical name: input13
                logical name: /dev/input/event13
           *-input:1
                product: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
                physical id: 1
                logical name: input14
                logical name: /dev/input/event14
           *-input:2
                product: HDA Intel PCH Line
                physical id: 2
                logical name: input15
                logical name: /dev/input/event15
           *-input:3
                product: HDA Intel PCH Line Out
                physical id: 3
                logical name: input16
                logical name: /dev/input/event16
           *-input:4
                product: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone
                physical id: 4
                logical name: input17
                logical name: /dev/input/event17
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: d4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:f2200000-f23fffff ioport:f2400000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: d4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f7100000-f71fffff ioport:f2100000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: enp3s0
                version: 11
                serial: 74:d0:2b:a1:af:42
                size: 1Gbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-41-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.1.30 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
                resources: irq:18 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7100fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: d4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:27
           *-pci
                description: PCI bridge
                product: ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge
                vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 03
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
                resources: iomemory:202031310-20203130f ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:f2600000-f27fffff ioport:f2800000(size=2097152)
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7217000-f72173ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 6.8.0-41-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 6.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.04
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Z87 Express LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
           *-pnp00:00
                product: PnP device PNP0c01
                physical id: 0
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:01
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 1
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:02
                product: PnP device PNP0b00
                physical id: 2
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
           *-pnp00:03
                product: PnP device INT3f0d
                vendor: Interphase Corporation
                physical id: 3
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:04
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 4
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:05
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 5
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:06
                product: PnP device PNP0501
                physical id: 6
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=serial
           *-pnp00:07
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 7
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:28 ioport:f070(size=8) ioport:f060(size=4) ioport:f050(size=8) ioport:f040(size=4) ioport:f020(size=32) memory:f7216000-f72167ff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: Samsung SSD 850
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 2B6Q
                serial: S2RBNX0J524197X
                size: 465GiB (500GB)
                capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=de63ba76-9b89-463a-8682-4dc787afc33c logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
              *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: mkfs.fat
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   version: FAT32
                   serial: dc58-87b2
                   size: 1073MiB
                   capacity: 1074MiB
                   capabilities: boot fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
              *-volume:1
                   description: EFI partition
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   serial: b470d02d-ac59-4e2d-9956-a3e681372936
                   capacity: 2047MiB
              *-volume:2
                   description: Linux swap volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                   logical name: /dev/sda3
                   version: 1
                   serial: 7543cfb3-ca85-4ac1-b9d0-6a6bc23e749e
                   size: 8190MiB
                   capacity: 8191MiB
                   capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                   configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
              *-volume:3
                   description: EFI partition
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                   logical name: /dev/sda4
                   serial: eab0539f-f9af-40f1-89b8-61a61cf32175
                   capacity: 454GiB


I’m voting to close this question because off-topic rant (https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)

I don't understand. it's an issue that multiple people are experiencing and nvidia is perfectly on-topic there are even tags for it. which I used.

This isn't written as a problem (question) we can help with; it's written as a rant pointing elsewhere and not giving details of any clear problem you have that you wish for us to solve. If you're trying to highlight a bug, this isn't a bug tracker as problems need to be reported on bug trackers for developers to become aware of them - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

this is a place where people who have fiddled around more give solutions to those who have fiddled around less. I wrote my question within that context : if there's a way to use 560 currently without all the drawbacks I'd like to know how.

Please list your system specs, what version of Ubuntu you're using, the method you used to install the driver, etc. All of these things are needed for us to know what the problem is. For all we know, you might be downloading the wrong version directly from the Nvidia website and trying to manually install it without the proper configuration.

May I ask why you're not using the sudo ubuntu-drivers command to install the drivers?

Also, if the new driver doesn't perform well, how is that taking advantage of increased performance?

i don't know, should I? isn't sudo ubuntu-drivers what the driver gui uses under the hood?

i've seen 555 run it runs well despite the suspend issues. but yeah that's why I'm on 535 now. I'd rather have suspend functionality. 560 doesn't run at all
I've updated my question with system specs

btw I should really note that this is not normal. there's rarely been a nvidia release this bad in probably 20 years of ubuntu.

Can you add to your post the kernel you are using? I've had issues with the v545 driver not working and throwing errors during module compilation when trying to reinstall it, and the only change I can think of is a kernel update. So I suspect there is some incompatibility between the kernel and the 545 driver.

Linux 6.8.0-41-generic

This question is still without any release details, so what options are available isn't known... Have you considered switching kernel stacks? as 6.8 is used by LTS releases and thus only one kernel stack option. It still appears to me mostly rant with few actual specifics allowing for problem solving.

I have a full suite of system specs. I can't upgrade kernels (I have tried) since as you can see I boot ZFS.

Seems related to launchpad bug 2037004, but the issue was fixed for me 7/31 for 3080 hardware. However I see reports of the issue 8/30. ubuntu-drivers only offered a reduced set of drivers (up to 535 or 545 with graphics-drivers ppa). Even the 550 driver was pulled from 22.04. No explanation was ever given, but looks like a combination of a db not updated and some hardware incompatibilities for the later drivers. The driver packages were present and could be manually installed.
